# Updating a string field in all documents found in a collection in Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I would like to know if it is possible to update all of the documents found in a collection in Firestore. I am able to get all the documents in a list like so:

```
mFirebaseFirestore.collection("Events").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getId());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

But, I cant seem to be able to update all documents, or similar strings within those documents at once. If the above is not possible, what could be a work around as far as to update all the documents.

Comment: Are you sure, that the code in your question is exactly like the code, which you use? Because you close the for clause and then have an else clause, which you don't close.

Comment: Yes, I am using the code just to get all the documents ids, which then are store in a list. My problem is that i dont know how to get each document id stored in that list and update them individually systematically.

Comment: better to write firebase function for it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj's method will work but may lead to doing a lot of writes. As Doug mentioned, you may like to do it in a batch write.

```
void getData() {

    mFirebaseFirestore.collection("Events").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    list.add(document.getId());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
                updateData(list); // *** new ***
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

}

void updateData(ArrayList list) {

    // Get a new write batch
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

    // Iterate through the list
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {

        // Update each list item
        DocumentReference ref = db.collection("Events").document(list.get(k));
        batch.update(ref, "field_you_want_to_update", "new_value");

    }

    // Commit the batch
    batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            // Yay its all done in one go!
        }
    });

}
```

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: Thank you! I was able to modify the code based on my needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single operation that will update multiple documents based on som search criteria.  You will have to iterate the query results as you're doing now, then individually update each of the documents.  You could possibly also use a [transaction or batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to perform the updates atomically, but that will not let you prevent iterating all the documents in the initial query result.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Now, how would I go on about reading each document individually from that list?

Comment: You're already doing that in the code you showed.  All queries read documents and return their snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update all the documents in a collection first you have have to retrieve all of them in a List and then iterate that list and update them. Here is a sample code:-

```
for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
    firestore.collection("Events").document(list.get(k))
        .update("Key", value).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.i("Update", "Value Updated");

                }
             })
             .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error In Updating Details: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps @CaptKenpa

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed.